# do while loop with nested two while

Tags: java

I get the problem, when I compile my program not error, but when I running the program doesn't perform anything. JDK have been installed. Other program running well. what is my problem?? because nested loop ??

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintStream.*;
public class Latihan3 {
  public static void main (String args []){
  int data1=0;
  int data2=0;

  char temp1;
  char temp2;
  boolean done=false;
  String simpan1;
  String simpan2;
  String konversi;
  String jenis="";
  String kata1="";
  String kata2="";
  FileInputStream fis1 =null;
  FileInputStream fis2 =null;
  FileOutputStream fos =null;
  FileOutputStream fos2 =null;
  DataOutputStream dos =null;
  DataOutputStream dos2 =null;
  PrintStream ps = null;
  PrintStream ps2 = null;

  try {
  fis1 = new FileInputStream ("D://hasil2.txt");
  fis2 = new FileInputStream ("D://latihan.txt");
  fos = new FileOutputStream ("D://latihan2.txt");
  fos2 = new FileOutputStream ("D://katabaru.txt");
  dos = new DataOutputStream (fos);
  dos2 = new DataOutputStream (fos2);
  ps = new PrintStream (dos);
  ps2 = new PrintStream (dos2);
  } catch (IOException e){
   System.out.println ("Eksepsi :"+e.getMessage());
  }
  try{


  do { 


     data1=fis1.read();
     temp1=(char)data1;
     data2=fis2.read();
     temp2=(char)data2; 



     while (temp1 != ' ' ){
      simpan1 = String.valueOf(temp1);
      kata1 = kata1.concat (simpan1); 
      data1=fis1.read();
      temp1=(char)data1; 
     }

     data1=fis1.read();
     temp1=(char)data1; 
     jenis = String.valueOf(temp1);
     data1=fis1.read();
     temp1=(char)data1;


     while (temp2 != ' ' ){
      simpan2 = String.valueOf(temp2);
      kata2 = kata2.concat (simpan2);
      data2=fis2.read();
      temp2=(char)data2;

     }

     if (kata1.equals (kata2)){
      ps.print (kata1);
      ps.print (' ');
      ps.print (jenis);
      ps.print ('/');
      kata1="";
      kata2="";
     }else {
      ps.print (kata2);
      ps2.print (kata2);
      ps2.print (' ');
      ps2.print (jenis);
      ps2.print ('/');
      ps.print (' ');
      ps.print ('?');
      ps.print ('/');
      kata1="";
      kata2="";
     }


  } while (data2 != -1);

 System.out.println ("data telah dimasukan");
 } catch (IOException e){
  System.out.println ("Eksepsi :"+e.getMessage());
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Learn more about organizing code in functions.

Comment: If you have no space characters in `fis1`, your first inner while loop will run forever.

Comment: Does your program block, or exits without output?

Comment: What do you expect your program to do? What output do you expect? What output does it give?

Comment: I suggest that you MUST learn how to debug!

Answer (score 0):

If your program doesn't even print "data telah dimasukan", then there is another error. Maxybe you forgot to compile again?

Answer (score 0):

1. Program cannot perform anything just "because nested loop". Looks like there's a problem in logics of your code, or in input data. Currently is's hard to trace the problem, but you can help specifying what this program is supposed to do, what input files can contain, what output are you expecting.
2. You may use your IDE's debugger in order to check what's actually happening in your program. Also, you may add some debug output in order to get intermediate values of your strings.
3. There's long function with at least one code duplication. It would be much easier to find the problem, if you refactor it a little ([extract methods](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html), rename variables from fis1, fos2 and temp1 to some meaningful names)